# Calculate 10 random generated digits

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the expected number of random digits that should be generated to obtain three consecutive zeros?

Now how can i proceed with this problem using the Theorem for Conditioning on Random Variables?

I tried to start with $$E[X]=E[E(X|Y)]$$=$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty E(X|Y=i)P(Y=i)$$

So now, i am thinking how can i proceed using the formula. I know that there are 10 digits and the chance of 1 zero is 1/10 and 9/10 is no zero. But how can i make this into a general formula??

Can anybody explain in words and break down , what the book gives as an answer?

[image]

Comment: [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364038/expected-number-of-coin-tosses-to-get-five-consecutive-heads) talking about how many flips to get five consecutive heads.  You can use the same method employed by the answers there for your specific problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz how to use the definition $$E[X]=E[E(X|Y)]$$

Comment: Have a look to this answer. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839496/expected-number-of-tosses-to-get-3-consecutive-heads/1839505#1839505

Comment: @callculus how can i threat E[X|Y] as a random variable. It is still unclear to me. In the examples they dont use the formula