# Expected Number of Attempts for Success in a 'Stepped System'

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question somewhat  similar to: [Expected number of tosses to get 3 consecutive Heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839496/expected-number-of-tosses-to-get-3-consecutive-heads?rq=1&newreg=bf1cf44010dd40a182fe3d3d0fe1fbc0)
However for my purposes, you don't have to re-start from the beginning of a sequence if you fail a trial (usually), and I'm not sure if I'm calculating this correctly. The system in question come from a game, a part of which involves upgrading your gear, which is summarized below:

\begin{array}{||c}
Level & Chance\ Of\ Success & Penalty\\
\hline
0\ to\ 1 & 100 & NA\\
1\ to\ 2 & 100 & NA\\
2\ to\ 3 & 100 & NA\\
3\ to\ 4 & 100 & NA\\
4\ to\ 5 & 100 & NA\\
5\ to\ 6 & 50 & NA\\
6\ to\ 7 & 50 & Lose\ 1\ level\\
7\ to\ 8 & 50 & Lose\ 1\ level\\
8\ to\ 9 & 40 & Lose\ 1\ level\\
9\ to\ 10 & 40 & Lose\ 1\ level\\
10\ to\ 11 & 40 & Reset\ to\ 0\\
\end{array}

Here is my attempt so far at figuring this out (my apologies if I'm completely wrong...):

-Levels 1 to 5 are self explanatory, 5 trials to get to level 5.

-Level 5 to 6 is simply levels 1-5 trials + 2 more trials.

-Levels 6 to 7 and 7 to 8 are equal to (previous trials) + (current level - 5)*2 + 2.

-Levels 8 to 9 and 9 to 10 are equal to (previous trials) + (((current level - 5)+4)*2)+1.

-Level 10 to 11 is equal to (previous trials * 2) + 1 [99 trials in total keeping in mind you cannot have fractional trials].

If I'm wrong please correct me, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_{i,i+1}$ be the expected number of steps needed to reach level $i+1$ from level $i$. It is obvious that
$$
S_{i,i+1} = 1\quad\text{for}\ 0 \leq i \leq 4
$$
For $i = 5$, we have
$$
S_{5, 6} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 + S_{5, 6})\ \Rightarrow\ S_{5,6} = 2
$$
because with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we reach level $6$ after one step; with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we remain in level $5$ which costs one step and we need extra $S_{5, 6}$ steps to reach level $6$. Similarly, 
for $i = 6, 7$, we have
$$
S_{i, i+1} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot (1 + S_{i - 1, i} +S_{i, i + 1})\ \Rightarrow\ S_{i,i+1} = 2 + S_{i-1,i}
$$
and for $i = 8, 9$, we have
$$
S_{i, i+1} = \frac{2}{5} \cdot 1 + \frac{3}{5} \cdot (1 + S_{i-1,i} + S_{i, i + 1}) \ \Rightarrow\ S_{i,i+1} = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{3}{2}S_{i-1,i}
$$
and for $i = 10$, we have
$$
S_{10,11} = \frac{2}{5} \cdot 1 + \frac{3}{5} \cdot (1 + S_{0,1} + S_{1, 2} + \cdots + S_{10,11}) \ \Rightarrow\ S_{10,11} = \frac{5}{2} + \frac{3}{2}(S_{0,1} + \cdots + S_{9, 10})
$$

Consequently, the expected total # of steps needed to reach level $11$ from level $0$ is
$$
S_{0,1} + S_{1,2} + \cdots + S_{10,11}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the input, though I have to admit I'm a bit confused on the 'S notation' (which is completely my fault). If I'm understanding this correctly, if i = 6, the 'English' equivalent would be: The # of steps needed to get from 6 to 6+1 is equal to 2+ the # of steps needed to get from 6-1, 5 -> 7 total steps? I'm not sure what is going on there.

Comment: @bdolebli To reach level $7$ from level $6$, with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, you directly go to level $7$ (this costs one step); and with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, you go first to level $5$ (one step) and then you need to reach level $6$ from level $5$ and then reach level $7$ from level $6$. Therefore, $$S_{6, 7} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot (1 + S_{5, 6} + S_{6, 7})$$ Solving this equation, we can obtain $$S_{6, 7} = 2 + S_{5, 6}$$ and if we know the value of $S_{5, 6}$, we can know $S_{6, 7}$.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now, thank you very much for the help.