# Expected coin toss to get three consecutive heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Alice and Bob play a game. Bob can play $\$1$ to flip coin. If he gets three consecutive heads, like HHH, then he gets $\$12$.  Is this a good game for Bob?

I think the answer is yes but I can see why it can also be no. In this thread [Expected number of tosses to get 3 consecutive Heads](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839496/expected-number-of-tosses-to-get-3-consecutive-heads) it is shown that the expected number of coin flips to get 3 consecutive heads is $14$. So that makes me think that it's unfair for Bob. But then I tried doing a markov chain calculation by writing the transition matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

First state is where we start or where we go when we get a tails (no heads in the sequence). Second state is with one heads, third state is with two heads, and fourth state is with 3 heads.

I calculated the matrix to the power of $12$ and I looked at the top-right corner entry, and it was $0.58$. So this makes me think yes, it is a good game for Bob because $0.58 > 0.5$ which means you expect to get into HHH state with 12 or less coin flips.

What do you think? Which interpretation is right?

Comment: Your first analysis is correct. It is not a good game for Bob. I'm not well versed in Markov chains, so I can't comment about your second approach.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends crucially upon what you mean by "he gets \$12".

If you mean that he has paid \$3 but then wins \$12, it is not a good game for him.

However, if he is effectively paying \$3 but winning \$15 then this is a good game for him because $15>14$.

Comment: Yes he pays $3$ and wins $12$. Why is the markov chain analysis wrong?

Comment: The 0.58 means his probability of having just won \$12 is 0.58. However he will have paid \$12 to have this number of tosses. This is not a good reason to play the game!