# Fair Coin, How to calculate Expected Value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I was reading: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1839505/1015824

But still I can't understand how to calculate any of the following: $(3|), (3|H)...$

I know that $E(x)=E(E(X|Y))$ but I don't know how to calculate the above expected value...

Answer (score 1):

The expected number of tosses to obtain three consecutive heads given that the first toss is a tail equals one plus the expected number of tosses to obtain three consecutive heads (starting from that point). $$\mathsf E(3H\mid T) = 1+\mathsf E(3H)$$

This is the $(1+x)$ factor in the original solution.   The factor of $\tfrac 12$ is the probability for the first toss showing a tail.

So are the other terms evaluated.

Comment: 1) and $(3)$ is equal to?... We are back to the original problem as we want to calculate this... 2) Can you explain why "equals one plus the expected number"... it's the first time I see something like this (I was used to use the definition of expected value to calculate it)

Comment: 1) $$\small\begin{align}\mathsf E(3H)&=\mathsf P(T)\mathsf E(3H\mid T)+\mathsf P(HT)\mathsf E(3H\mid HT)+\mathsf P(HHT)\mathsf E(3H\mid HHT)+\mathsf P(HHH)\mathsf E(3H\mid HHH)\\&=\tfrac 12(1+\mathsf E(3H))+\tfrac 14(2+\mathsf E(3H))+\tfrac 18(3+\mathsf E(3H))+\tfrac18\cdot3\end{align}$$  Then solve for $\mathsf E(3H)$

Comment: 2)  The expected count of tosses to terminate given the first toss is a tail equals *that first toss* plus *the expected count of the rest of the tosses*.

Comment: You should edit the answer linked to in this question (or add your own answer there) to add the insights given here, to help future readers who stumble upon that question.