# computing the expecation of flips for three consecutive heads?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am trying to understand the solution on how to compute the number of expectation to get three consecutive heads of a fair coin.
The solutions says let $E$  be the expectation. Then
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}E + \frac{1}{2} (E + 1) +  \frac{1}{4} (E + 2) +  \frac{1}{8} (E + 3)
$$
and solving this equation one gets $E = 14$.

I am struggling to understand how this works. It seems that we just start at count $E$... any clarification appreciated.

Comment: Does this help ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839496/expected-number-of-tosses-to-get-3-consecutive-heads

Answer (score 1):

Where does this come from? Does it give $14$ as a solution?

It is not the equation I would have written, but instead $$E=\frac12(1+E)+\frac14(2+E)+\frac18(3 +E)+\frac18(3)$$ since  you flip

(a) a tail and start again or

(b) a head and a tail and start again or

(c) two heads and a tail and start again or

(d) three heads and stop.